# R encounters a fatal error when using minqa

Tags: r

I am using R package `minqa` to do maximum likelihood estimation.
Everytime I run `newuoa()` from the package (also other method), it cause a fatal error in R, and the session was terminated. I believe my code before that does not have a problem because `maxLik` gives me results. I want to reproduce the same results using `newuoa()`.

Here is code I used with random generated data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(maxLik)
library(minqa)

set.seed(5)
data <- data.frame(eu1=rnorm(1000, mean=15, sd=2),
                   eu2=rnorm(1000, mean=19, sd=2),
                   eu3=rnorm(1000, mean=22, sd=2),
                   action=sample(1:3,1000, replace=T))
data$y1 <- ifelse(data$action==1, 1, 0)
data$y2 <- ifelse(data$action==2, 1, 0)
data$y3 <- ifelse(data$action==3, 1, 0)

L_qre<-function(theta){
  p1 <- exp(theta*(data$eu1-data$eu2))/(exp(theta*(data$eu1-data$eu2)) + 1 + exp(theta*(data$eu3-data$eu2)))
  p2 <- 1/(exp(theta*(data$eu1-data$eu2)) + 1 + exp(theta*(data$eu3-data$eu2)))
  p3 <- exp(theta*(data$eu3-data$eu2))/(exp(theta*(data$eu1-data$eu2)) + 1 + exp(theta*(data$eu3-data$eu2)))
  Li <- log(p1*data$y1+p2*data$y2+p3*data$y3)
  sum(Li)
}
qre <- maxLik(L_qre, start=0.5)
summary(qre)
--------------------------------------------
Maximum Likelihood estimation
Newton-Raphson maximisation, 5 iterations
Return code 1: gradient close to zero (gradtol)
Log-Likelihood: -108.7125 
1  free parameters
Estimates:
     Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)
[1,] -0.04697    0.03109  -1.511   0.131
--------------------------------------------

qre2 <- newuoa(0.5, L_qre)
```

I have tried it in Mac M1 also Mac Intel, and tried to update both R and RStudio.

Here is the session information from Mac Intel:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.7.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] minqa_1.2.5      maxLik_1.5-2     miscTools_0.6-28 lubridate_1.9.2 
 [5] forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.3      purrr_1.0.2     
 [9] readr_2.1.4      tidyr_1.3.0      tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.4.3   
[13] tidyverse_2.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.4      compiler_4.3.1    Rcpp_1.0.11       tidyselect_1.2.0 
 [5] scales_1.2.1      lattice_0.21-8    R6_2.5.1          generics_0.1.3   
 [9] munsell_0.5.0     pillar_1.9.0      tzdb_0.4.0        rlang_1.1.1      
[13] utf8_1.2.3        stringi_1.7.12    timechange_0.2.0  cli_3.6.1        
[17] withr_2.5.0       magrittr_2.0.3    digest_0.6.33     grid_4.3.1       
[21] rstudioapi_0.15.0 haven_2.5.3       hms_1.1.3         sandwich_3.0-2   
[25] lifecycle_1.0.3   vctrs_0.6.3       glue_1.6.2        zoo_1.8-12       
[29] fansi_1.0.4       colorspace_2.1-0  tools_4.3.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.